# How can we show that $f:aff S\to E^{k+1}$ is continuous?

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis

> Let $S\equiv conv \{x_1,x_2,...x_{k+1}\}$ be a $k$-dimensional simplex   **[i.e., $dim\{x_1,x_2,..,x_{k+1}\}=k\ $  i.e., the smallest subspace containing the set $\{x_1,x_2,..,x_{k+1} \}$ is of dimension $k$ ]**.
>
> We have to show the function $f:aff S\to E^{k+1}$  defined by $f(\alpha_1 x_1+...+\alpha_{k+1}x_{k+1})=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{k+1})$
> is continuous.

Here $aff S$ denotes the affine hull of $S$ and $E^{k+1}$ is the Euclidean space of dimension $k+1$.

This is a part of a theorem in convex analysis which states that **"Let S$\equiv conv \{x_1,...,x_{k+1}\}$ be a k-dimensional simplex. Then relative interior of S$\neq\phi$. "**

In the proof of this theorem the above question has been used but I can't prove it.

Please give some hints.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that the function $g: \text{aff}(S) - \{ x_1\} \to R^{k+1} $ with $g(x) = f(x+x_1) - f(x_1)$ is a linear function.